# Xcode 7/Swift: Save value of slider and send to child class when view changes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to have the value of a slider on a certain view appear in a text box on a child view. But when the second view loads, it seems that the value of the slider is lost and set to nil. How would I preserve the value of that slider before the view changes in order to use the most recent value in the child view? Here is some relevant code (I want to set the textbox "redTextBox" to be the "changeRed" slider's value):

PARENT CLASS--------------------------------

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var changeRed: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var changeGreen: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var changeBlue: UISlider!

var r: Float = 0
var g: Float = 0
var b: Float = 0

@IBAction func slideRed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: changeRed.value, green: changeGreen.value, blue: changeBlue.value, alpha: 1.0)
     r = changeRed.value
     g = changeGreen.value
     b = changeBlue.value
}

@IBAction func slideGreen(sender: AnyObject) {
  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: changeRed.value, green: changeGreen.value, blue: changeBlue.value, alpha: 1.0)
     r = changeRed.value
     g = changeGreen.value
     b = changeBlue.value

}

@IBAction func slideBlue(sender: AnyObject) {
      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: changeRed.value, green: changeGreen.value, blue: changeBlue.value, alpha: 1.0)
     r = changeRed.value
     g = changeGreen.value
     b = changeBlue.value

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: changeRed.value, green: changeGreen.value, blue: changeBlue.value, alpha: 1.0)
}

......
}
```

---

CHILD CLASS----------------------------

```
class ColorValueVC: ViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var redTextBox: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var greenTextBox: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var blueTextBox: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    redTextBox.text = "\(changeRed.value)"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

---

Comment: u can just create some float variable in your child class then pass the slider value from parent class to it through segue, slider value is basically just float or double number anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child inherits from the parent view controller. What are you trying to achieve by doing this? If they're two view controllers where one segues to the other, then there should not be an inheritance link between them. Instead you pass data from A to B by implementing `prepareForSegue` in A.